# merging multiline command output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, formatting

I'm attempting to merge a command output into a single line, in order to print an output to show machine name, mount, and 'online' status.

here is how the output comes out:

```
Status of volume: mymount
Gluster process                             TCP Port  RDMA Port  Online  Pid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Brick mymachine01:/bricks/mymount/mylongcha
achtermnt                                   49156     0          Y       6648
Brick mymachine02:/bricks/mymount/mylongcha
achtermnt                                   49156     0          Y       6484
```

When I perform my command, and use a regular `| grep -i brick` I get this

```
Brick mymachine01:/bricks/mymount/mylongcha
Brick mymachine02:/bricks/mymount/mylongcha
```

Which doesn't show any of the other data I need, such as 'online'. I suspect this is happening because grep only looks for matching lines, and looking at the first output, the line is blank under the fields section, due to the data following the actual end of the mount point on the next line.

Is there a way to turn merge these two lines, as I need the data post the mount point for status and PID?

Output should look like this:

```
Brick mymachine01:/bricks/mymount/mylongchaachtermnt    49156     0     Y      6448
Brick mymachine02:/bricks/mymount/mylongcharahtermnt    49156     0     Y      6484
```

each on a single line. I will be adding a timestamp in front of each line in a script, but that's just preference.

Comment: yeah, just edited the original comment. Thanks man.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue. The command output is just folded to accommodate the screen width I guess. Can you also post a sample screenshot showing the output in the 2nd line as did above

Comment: As you see from https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Storage/2.0/html/Administration_Guide/sect-User_Guide-Monitor_Workload-Displaying_Volume_Status.html it does post in the same line properly

Comment: Did You try grep -A 2 ?

Comment: @theGlitchKing: Can you show us the value of `echo $COLUMNS`?

Comment: when I put the command into a script, and then echo $COLUMNS It looks like it wraps the entire output, instead of line by line.

@Inian I believe my issue may be different then I suspected.

Comment: @fane89 I did try the -A 2 option, and when ran manually (unscripted) it doesn't give me the output I needed.

Comment: @theGlitchKing: Run `echo $COLUMNS` in the command line and not in a script. It should return just a number. What is it?

Comment: @Inian the number output is 174

Comment: I take it back. Scripted the output looks the same when I use printf and enforce line breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash


mapfile -t HOST < <( gluster volume status all detail | grep brick | awk '{ print $4 }' | grep -oP "myHost\d+" )
mapfile -t MNT  < <( gluster volume status all detail | grep brick | awk '{ print $4 }' | grep -oP "\/bricks.+" )
mapfile -t STATUS < <( gluster volume status all detail | grep -i online  | awk '{ print $3 }' )

i=0;
for item in "${HOST[@]}"; do
   echo ${HOST[$i]} ${MNT[$i]} ${STATUS[$i]};
   let "i=i+1"
done
```

This have me the output, with each array printed in what looks like individual columns with the status.

I also had to use a different gluster command as well, which outputs the full mount in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

There is: `... | grep -i -A1 brick | paste -d "" - -`

Comment: I tried this, and the output is still wrapped on my long gluster mounts.